# Understanding partial derivative of a global section of a sheaf

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

This question comes from a paper of Vojta "A generalization of theorems of Faltings and Thue-Siegel-Roth-Wirsing":

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2152710?seq=23#metadata_info_tab_contents

Here is the situation: Let $C$ be a curve defined over a number field $k$, $B$ be the arithmetic scheme corresponding to $k$ ($B = \operatorname{Spec} R$ where $\operatorname{Frac}(R)=k$). Let $\pi: X \to B$ be an arithmetic surface assumed to be regular (viewed as a regular model of $C$).

On page 785, he defined the partial derivative of a section as follows:

> Let $\gamma$ be a section of a metrized line sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ on $X$, and let $P\in C(k)$, corresponding to a section $s: B \to X$. Then for integers $i\geq 0$, we shall now define the $i$-th "derivative" $D_{i}\gamma(P)$ as a section:
>   $$D_{i}\gamma \in \Gamma(B,s^{*}(\mathcal{L}\otimes\omega_{X/B}^{\otimes i})),$$
>   provided that $D_{j}(\gamma)=0$ for all $j=0,\ldots,i-1$. Fix a local section $\gamma_{0}$ of $\mathcal{L}$ which has neither a zero nor a pole at $P$; then
>   $$\gamma=\gamma_{0}\sum_{i \geq 0}a_{i}z^{i}$$
>   and $\gamma_{0}a_{i}z^{i}$ lies in the subsheaf
>   $$\mathcal{L}\otimes \mathcal{O}(-iP)\subset \mathcal{L}.$$
>   Its restriction to the image of $s$ is well-defined, independent of the choices of $z$ and $\gamma_{0}$, by the assumption on $i$. Using different local parameters $z$, it follows that this section is a well-defined element of the sheaf $s^{*}(\mathcal{L}\otimes \mathcal{O}(-iP))\cong s^{*}(\mathcal{L}\otimes \omega_{X/B}^{\otimes i})$ at every closed point of $B$.

It looks like the derivative section is chosen to be $\gamma_{0}a_{i}z^{i}$? I am not sure what he means here.

Another thing confusing me is the condition $D_{j}\gamma = 0$ for $j=0,\ldots,i-1$. How can one say something about $D_{j}\gamma$ before defining it?

I am just having trouble understanding what this paragraph means. Can anyone give some explanations/comments?

Thank you!

Comment: A formatting tip for the future: when you want to write $\operatorname{Spec}$ or other MathJax commands which aren't already present, the best way to do this is with \operatorname{Spec}. I've taken the liberty of fixing up your post with this change.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that.